# Wordpress one customizer for multiple pages

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm developing a website where I need a page-template for multiple pages (which can be created via the Pages section in the dashboard) with the same structure, but different images and texts.

How can I build a dynamic customizer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommended you to use this plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/ which is very helpful which can create a dynamic custom filed under each page and those data can be show on template